# A multi-stage model replenishment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a need, to make a multi-step process in which my, let's say "big model" will be updated every step and in the end saved to a database. For now, I made it this way:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StepOne()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StepOne(StepOneViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("StepTwo", "SameController", viewModel);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult StepTwo(StepOneViewModel stepOneViewModel)
    {
        var stepTwoViewModel = new StepTwoViewModel()
        {
            stepOneViewModel = stepOneViewModel
        };

        return View(stepTwoViewModel );
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult StepTwo(StepTwoViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("StepThree", "SameController", viewModel);
    }
```

... And so on. This approach seems to be good because it's strongly typed in a view, and I can have a separate validation for every "smaller" view model. On the other hand, I have to pass every parameter of the previous view model via `Hidden` inputs (making a partial for example, not to mess the code too much).
But is there another, better way to do so ? Is it possible to pass the whole object with many properties to the hidden or something similar ?

Comment: You could consider a separate db table to store interm results and update the record there from step to step. Downside is a bit higher response latency, upside is an opportunity to recover progress if something went wrong. Although some cleanup needs to be done, as this table is very likely to quickly fill up with junk. So some more work is another downside

Comment: Instead of rendering everything as hidden fields, can you use session to store those properties temporarily? Just an idea.

Comment: This is actually a good use case for sessions. It's still better to persist the data in a permanent location like a database table, but it's perfectly okay to use the session for this. Just be aware that if the user is idle too long before completing the process, they may lose all their previous step submissions if the session expires. You could implement an AJAX "ping", though, to keep the session active while they're on any of the steps.

Comment: Thanks for every answer. I was thinking about saving each step to the database, but implementing full control about this would be much longer than gathering the full model and than perform a db save. It's the first time I've used session for real but seems to work nice :)